# Delete non-empty folder without permission

Tags: permissions, delete

In my home directory on my University's server, there are some directories owned by another user.

I'd like to get rid of them, but unfortunately it complains about me not having permission. I can delete files in my home directory without a problem, but the recursive delete doesn't work for directories, since I can't delete the contents.

How can I get rid of them without bothering the administrators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You can't**... If, as I assume, you have a restricted account without the privileges to run `sudo` and access the folders as root.

As far as I know, there should (and it would be a serious security issue if not) be NO chance to get ownership of another user's data except for root users. So you have to ask your local admin to do this for you!

And think: What sense would it make to have two types of users (admin/restricted), if everybody just could steal other users' files?

Comment: Well, I am the owner of a parent directory and this is restricting me from managing it. In my opinion it would make sense for me to be able to modify it. (I could delete files, but I can't delete a directory?)

Comment: Possessing / having rights on a parent directory does not imply having the same rights/ownership on its contents (files an subdirectories). There can be differences.

Comment: As I just learned, there is the possibility that sometimes users that are members of the same group have full access to each other's files, depending on the group settings. But anyway: Taking ownership of someone else's files is kind of HACKING and without him/her approval definitely ILLEGAL!!! Don't risk punishment, this isn't worth it!

Comment: These files are cluttering MY home directory. They are the remnants of a git repository and on their own are completely worthless. I don't want to assume ownership of them, I want to get rid of them. If it is not possible, then that's that, but don't talk about what a bad idea it is to clean up my own home...

Comment: These files are in your home folder, but also are owned by a different user (who obviously had high privileges to put them there). So whoever put them there should take them back away. And I never said that a tidied up home directory is bad, but you easily can get punished if you break your University's rights management. Talk with the teacher in charge of this server, he is the only one that can help you.

Comment: Alright then, it is unfortunate there is no other way. And btw, the person who put those directories there did not have any special permissions. They are in a subdirectory of my home that I created and gave him access to and it bothers me I can't delete it now.